# Microphone not set to input device Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I have upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 from 18.04, after upgrading i noticed that the microphone is not set as input device in the settings, it appears blank like shown in the below picture, my pc model is Dell Precision 3440

[image]

However when i choose this list, i can see my system microphone and my headset microphone, the only problem is there is no microphone set automatically in this selection field. After setting the system microphone, if i try to connect my headset, again this field turns in to blank.

I tried to do

> options snd_hda_intel index=0 model=[YOUR_MODEL_SETTING]

as mentioned on arch wiki, but it made it worse, because after setting this, i cant find any of my microphones at the GUI, this problem occurs only if i unplug or insert my headset.

Update: after doing software updates shown by system this issue got fixed ( i have no idea what got updated ), try to install the latest updates once you upgrade to ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Check if this helps you. https://askubuntu.com/a/1294310/1112104. :))

Comment: what does `pacmd list-sources` say? We need to look inside to make an educated guess

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have gnome-alsamixer installed.

I had it installed in Ubuntu 18.04, and when I upgraded to 20 I started having similar issues. I removed it using `sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-alsamixer` and it resolved most audio issues for me.

PulseAudio (pavucontrol) also didn't work for me until I removed alsamixer.

I still occasionally have to switch audio devices using pavucontrol instead of through Settings but it's better than it not working recognizing devices at all.

Comment: i checked, i didnt have gnome-alsamixer installed.