# VLC plays through bluetooth speaker, but not brave browser

Tags: sound, bluetooth

I have my anker speaker connected, and selected in output under settings, sound. VLC plays sound through the bluetooth speaker, but brave browser does not. Brave plays through the onboard speakers. How can I get all sound to play through the bluetooth speaker? Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe the system is not automatically setting your speaker as volume output.

Try this method, read fully before implementing

-- install [sound Input & output device chooser](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/) from gnome extensions

-- then you can manually select the volume output easily from the top panel like this

[image]

alternatively,

1..  you can do this by setting

[image]

2.. use PulseAudio  see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/414430/1112104)

hope this help...  :))

Comment: The bluetooth speaker was selected in sound settings before, but unsuccessful. Added the gnome extension, still unsuccessful. Fiddled with installing some dependencies of pulseaudio, and it finally works now. I'm not sure which solved the problem, but once instance was `sudo apt-get install libflashsupport padevchooser pulseaudio-module-hal pulseaudio-module-x11`. Thanks!